# How to print a particular value from dweet?

Tags: python, dweet.io

I have an output from dweepy as :

```
[{'content': {'mouse_x': 271,
   'mouse_y': 285,
   'tilt_x': 0,
   'tilt_y': 0,
   'tilt_z': 82},
  'created': '2018-02-10T06:03:02.680Z',
  'thing': 'my_thing_name'}]
```

My input was :

```
dweepy.get_latest_dweet_for('my_thing_name')
```

Question :

How to print value of `mouse_x` value alone from above dweet output ?

What i tried was :

```
dweepy.dweet_for('my_thing_name', {'': 'mouse_x'})
```

which gave me output :

```
{'content': {'': 'mouse_x'},
 'created': '2018-02-10T06:23:20.320Z',
 'thing': 'my_thing_name',
 'transaction': '6f295639-a667-48ff-bbbf-6dda111333d1'}
```

**How can i print value 271 for `mouse_x` ?**

Comment: The result of the `get_latest_dweet_for` is a `dictionary`, if you assign the value of `a = dweepy.get_latest_dweet_for('my_thing_name')` then you can get the value of `mouse_x` by doing `a['content']['mouse_x']`

Comment: let me check that out

Comment: got ouput from : (a[0]['content']['mouse_x'])

Comment: Yes that's right because you have a list of dictionaries as a response, the [0] is used to access the first dictionary and then the `content->mouse_x` accesses the content accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the content you are `dweeting` with the `name` as `my_thing_name`, let us assume that you have `dweet_for()` as follows initially

```
dweepy.dweet_for('my_thing_name', {'mouse_x': 271, 'mouse_y': 285, 'tilt_x': 0, 'tilt_y': 0, 'tilt_z': 82})
```

Which creates a `dweet` with name as `my_thing_name`. Now when you query for the `dweet` using `dweepy.get_latest_dweet_for()` you are returned a dictionary as follows

```
a = dweepy.get_latest_dweet_for('my_thing_name')
```

Result is a list of `object` whose keys are `content`, `thing` and `created`. For retrieving the content for key `mouse_x` you need to access the object inside the dweet response's `content` dictionary.

```
[{u'content': {u'mouse_y': 285, u'mouse_x': 271, u'tilt_z': 82, u'tilt_x': 0, u'tilt_y': 0}, u'thing': u'my_thing_name', u'created': u'2018-02-10T06:39:53.715Z'}]
```

This can be done by doing `a[0]['content']['mouse_x']` which will return the value `271`. This will however work only with the first `dweet` object. If there are multiple objects returned you can loop through the items and access the `mouse_x` value by using `a[i]['content']['mouse_x']` where `i` corresponds to the index of the items.

```
>>> a[0]['content']['mouse_x']
271
```

Comment: thank you Sudheesh , got output from print(a[0]['content']['mouse_x'])